# Wrong JDK Version? glassfish

Tags: glassfish, java-6

I installed JDK 1.6 b45 and tried to get glassfish v2.2 running.
when I try starting it I always get the following error thrown:

```
[#|2013-06-18T08:50:20.196+0200|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ee._CORBA_.rpc.encoding|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;;_RequestID=29fde611-2769-4cdb-a37c-ceeb07dd24f2;|"IOP00711413: (INTERNAL) Could not find the expected Value Handler implementation in the JDK: Wrong JDK Version?"
```

I cant figure out where the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Our team is seeing the same error We're on

Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 Patch19 ((v2.1 Patch25)(9.1_02 Patch31)) (build b01-p19)

Possibly as a result of this error, possibly not, we're not seeing application logs (System.out, Logger.debug) statements in our domain1 server.log file.  Is anyone having that issue as well?

Comment: Our issue started occurring when we upgraded to JDK 1.6 b51 however.

Comment: Try and swith back to JDK1.6 b31 just for glassfish. that should help (see my answer below).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What fixed it for me was going to JDK 1.6b31. I have no idea why this works but we use it on many pcs now and it works just fine!

Comment: The only problem is I can't switch to an older version of the JDK due to security issues on my server.

Answer (score 4):

Ok i found the solution on Oracle support here is what they say

"The warning can be ignored.  If you wish to prevent it from being reported the Corba logging level can be raised to SEVERE, either by specifying the logging level in a Java logging properties file:

javax.enterprise.resource.corba.level=SEVERE
or directly in the client itself:

Logger.getLogger("javax.enterprise.resource.corba").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
This issue will be corrected in GlassFish Server 2.1.1.21 when available."

Comment: this didnt fix it for me. anyways. i will post my solution now as answer and thx for helping!

Comment: "i found the solution on Oracle support" where did you find that, could you send a link? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error began appearing in Java 6 >= u45. It is safe to ignore. You can run the following to stop it from appearing:

```
asadmin set server.log-service.module-log-levels.corba=SEVERE
```

Comment: Where did you read that this Exception is safe to ignore? Could you send an a link? Thanks!

Comment: I wish I had a definitive online source I could cite. One of our developers investigated this issue thoroughly and came to this conclusion. We ran with this log setting, which just suppresses the errors, in production for 2 years with no apparent negative effects. Note, this was with GF2, we've since moved on to GF3. For GF3, our devs asked me to add a jvm-option: `-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton`, I don't know the full reasons why, but I think it was related. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I didn't find any official source either. I just removed the warning.